# Disable startup program super user authentication

Tags: linux, sudoers

I want my VPN to run on startup after logging into my user account. Currently running Ubuntu 15.10. I have added the program to startup (/usr/bin/mullvad); however, it asks for authentication before opening.

"Authentication is needed to run 'usr/bin/mtunnel' as the super user"

I have added these entries to my sudoers file, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I still have to enter the password for my VPN to run.

```
john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mtunnel
john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mullvad
```

Any idea?

Full File

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification

 Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mtunnel, /usr/bin/mullvad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you so adamant on connecting to the VPN when you login? You might start it at boot, and then the VPN connection can be performed by `root` as part of the usual startup.

You can do it in a zillion different ways: you may add a line to `/etc/rc.local`, you may build a service around it (but the details depend on whether you are under `SysV` or `systemd`), or, easier still, you may put the following line

```
 @reboot /usr/bin/mullvad
```

in `crontab`. No more passwords then.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know I could run programs as root when the system is booting. I randomly decided to try out Ubuntu, so here I am. Worked perfectly.

Comment: This does not work as the network is not up yet when the crontab runs this command.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to execute those programs with `sudo`. With those two lines in `/etc/sudoers`, the user `john` will not be prompted for password when executing `sudo mtunnel` and `sudo mullvad`. Also, you could combine the two lines into one: `john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mtunnel, /usr/bin/mullvad`.

Comment: Oh I see. How would I run the program at startup without it requesting a authentication? Right now before the program runs it opens a dialog requesting authentication. I'm guessing that has to do with something else rather than sudo?

Comment: @john33303: Can you paste your complete `/etc/sudoers` into your original post? There might be something wrong with it.

Comment: Done. I also tried applying NOPASSWD to ALL which did work for everything else except for the VPN program. It still requested authentication.

Comment: @john33303: your `sudoers` file appears to be syntactically correct. So, based on that and your comment, the program apparently ignores the `sudoers` file. It may have a PAM configuration under `/etc/pam.d/`, but I don't have the program, so I can't inspect it.

Comment: Aw man. I guess I'll have to stick with entering the password which is annoying. If you want to take a look  at the program, the VPN is called MullVad. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score -1):

I had this authentication problem as well when I was developing a software. It appeared after I removed the software by `sudo apt remove` then try to run it from the source code, every single `Popen` action will pop up the authentication request.

I solved it by installing the software back (the live one), then I was able to run the dev software without any authentication request window. In your case, reinstalling the software might help.